# JSON DELETE method in objective C is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, rest, ios6

I have a with Json Delete method. I have surfed around the internet and got nothing.

Here is the code i have tried for the Json Delete Method. It simply returns "Json value failed"

```
NSString *posturl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/spottings/%@/media/%@.json?auth_token=%@",_BASE_API_URL,[_spotting_id_array objectAtIndex:button.tag],[_ex_media_id_array objectAtIndex:button.tag],_ex_auth_token_str];

NSLog(@"posturl:%@",posturl);
// Prepare string request

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",posturl]];

// Prepare URL request

NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

// Set the URL to request

[request setURL:url];

// Set the URL method

[request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *urlData, NSError *error){

    if ([urlData length] >0 && error == nil)
    {
        // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response

        NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        // parse the JSON response into an object

        // Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects

        _results = [data JSONValue];

        NSLog(@"_results:%@",_results);

    }
    else if ([urlData length] == 0 && error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
    }
    else if (error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Error code :

-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=10 \"Garbage after JSON\" UserInfo=0x8195240 {NSLocalizedDescription=Garbage after JSON}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request body should not normally contain any data either. `DELETE` is like `GET`, just a command sent to the server. There should not be a `Content-Type` header sent with it. Try removing that. Also, try printing out the contents of the `NSString *data` to see what you have.

Comment: Not deleting Showing the JSON response in  NSString *data

Comment: okay, so the error is saying that the JSON response is corrupted. can you print that out byte for byte so we can take a look at it?